# Clear $_SESSION variable with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, session, session-variables

I have inherited a file that adds a value to an input like this:

```
<input type="text" id="cityOrZip" class="form-control zip-field-to-be-validated" name="cityOrZip" value="<? if($_SESSION['locationCityOrZip']) { echo $_SESSION['locationCityOrZip']; } else { ?>80401<? } ?>">
```

A new functionality request for this page has led me to add a javascript function that checks for a specific query parameter in the URL and then update multiple (similar) fields in the form.  How can I ignore the session variable in my function that runs after checking the query parameter.

Here's my js which checks for the query parameter and then resets the fields:

```
if ( window.location.search.slice(1,8) === "movedto" ) {

function getQueryVariable(variable) {
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
       var pair = vars[i].split("=");
       if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
    }
    return(false);
}

var movedToLocation = getQueryVariable("movedto");

$('#cityOrZip, #filterCityOrZip').val(prettyLocation);
$('#locationType, #filterLocationType').val("Primary Care");
$( "#find-a-location-simple, #find-a-location" ).submit();
```

}

The problem that I'm seeing happen is that:

- When the query parameter conditional matches, the inputs are populated by my variables
- The PHP $_SESSION variable causes the inputs to reset to what the $_SESSION variable has stored.

Comment: You'd ignore it by not writing code which uses it, I guess.  It's not really clear to me what the problem is here.  Can you provide a more complete example and indicate specifically where there's a problem?

Comment: The Session variable is used to set the value of the input form.  I am adding  a variation of the page that uses a query variable.  I check to see if that query variable exists and then update the values of the inputs based on the query parameter.  However, these built in PHP $_SESSION variables are causing the input value to jump back and forth.  I would have never written it this way but I have inherited a jumbled up hot mess of jquery spaghetti

Comment: What do you mean by "causing the input value to jump back and forth"?  Can you provide an actual example of what's happening here?  So far you're just showing a value and asking how to not use that value.  Which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: David, added into the original question

Comment: `"The PHP $_SESSION variable causes the inputs to reset"` - Not client-side it doesn't. All the browser sees is the original value, any manipulations you perform on that value are entirely outside the scope of server-side sessions. Are you *reloading* the page? And effectively *re-executing* the server-side code and *resetting* your JavaScript? That would certainly explain the behavior. If that's the case then you'd need to have some logic which conditionally outputs that session value. What that condition is, that's up to you. But if you *sometimes* don't want to output it, you need an `if`.

Comment: I am not reloading the page but the final 'submit' does make an ajax call.

Comment: If you're not reloading the page (or any part of it) at all then you're going to have to find what's actually modifying that value.  Because client-side code has nothing to do with the server-side session, so your assumption regarding the culprit of the behavior is incorrect.  Once the page has been sent to the browser, server-side code is no longer involved at all.

Comment: I totally agree with you.  I wonder if the ajax call is causing the issue.  I'll keep digging, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in order for the session value to replace the javascript value that you are submitting the form (thus having php run).
You might need to add to your if statement to determine if a value was posted and use the posted value instead of the session value OR by replacing the stored session value.

I would suggest replacing the session value with the posted data before the form rather than adding to inline if statement.